# Flex: two small blocks and one big

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create two small block on the left side and one big on the right. I can make it with the height in px. but is there a way to make it without height indication? In real project there are image in big block so its  uncomfortable

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}

.cell {
  background: #ccc;
  border: solid 3px black;
  width: 50%;
}

.cell-1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .cell {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cell-1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .cell-2 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .cell-3 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Vertical Boxes</h1>
<p>Goal: Have one box on the left, and two boxes on the right that are stacked. All without nesting, so that the order of the boxes can be changed on smaller screen sizes.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell cell-1">
    <h2>One</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto pariatur rerum, illum accusantium cupiditate ipsam, eaque quae fugit cum assumenda ad. Modi, excepturi. Assumenda, nobis, consequatur? Aliquid repellendus quis, iure. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto pariatur rerum, illum accusantium cupiditate ipsam, eaque quae fugit cum assumenda ad. Modi, excepturi. Assumenda, nobis, consequatur? Aliquid repellendus quis, iure. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Iusto pariatur rerum, illum accusantium cupiditate ipsam, eaque quae fugit cum assumenda ad. Modi, excepturi. Assumenda, nobis, consequatur? Aliquid repellendus quis, iure. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Iusto pariatur rerum, illum accusantium cupiditate ipsam, eaque quae fugit cum assumenda ad. Modi, excepturi. Assumenda, nobis, consequatur? Aliquid repellendus quis, iure.
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell-2">
    <h2>Two</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste mollitia temporibus id sint illum doloremque pariatur nulla vel soluta, nostrum vitae, suscipit ea natus sed eaque in velit deserunt deleniti!
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell-3">
    <h2>Three</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, architecto perferendis voluptatum accusantium est ipsam fugit, laudantium fugiat nostrum consectetur earum. Asperiores, similique deleniti nobis nemo error, iste iure architecto.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify "without height indication".

Comment: You can easily do this using `grid`

Comment: I tried adding flex: 1; to .cell and it works.